# How to count the number of $groups in a aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, nosql-aggregation

I am querying my mongodb and ask for an aggregation. I would like to get the number of $groups that are output. What is the best way to do so ? Haven't figured out yet

My request is currently :

```
    db.getCollection('tickets').aggregate({
    $match: {
        many_criterias
    }
}, {$group: {
        _id: $node_id,
        amount: {
            $avg: "$amount_net"
        }
    }
})
```

I get an output which is data grouped by node_id, but how can I count the number of groups found?

In the following example, the expected answer is 4. 4 groups are found :

> ```
> _id / amount
> a / 12
> b / 14
> c / 16
> d / 18
> ```

Best

Comment: `count:{ $sum: 1 }`

Comment: This is not the answer.
$group:{_id:...,count:{ $sum: 1 }}

Will just tell me how many items they are per group. But not how many groups there are.

Comment: Then just count the length of the array returned.

Comment: I see you trynna help and thanks you so much for that.
However I can not get it to work,

db.getCollection('tickets').aggregate({
    $match: {}
}, {
$group: {
        _id: "$node_id",
        ticketPerNode: {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }},
{$project:{
            "_id": "$_id",
            "count": {$size: "$ticketPerNode"}
        }
})